# How do i find only part of the directory AppData\\Local?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this:

```
private void SearchForDoc()
{
    string t = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
}
```

Then the variable t contain:

```
C:\\Users\\bout0_000\\AppData\\Local\\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen
```

I want that t will contain only the `C:\\Users\\bout0_000\\` and if someone else username is `testme` so the the variable t will be: `C:\\Users\\testme\\`

And not all this long path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile");
```

if your current user is 'toto' this command will return 'C:\Users\toto'

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ulaga said you could use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);` to get the users directory, or you could just cut off after the first 3 folders.

```
string t = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
t = String.Join(@"\", t.Split('\\').ToList().Take(3).ToArray());
```